# How to get new window's properties after opening workspace with "vscode.openFolder"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension in which I prompt the user for a folder in their file system and open that folder using

```ts
await commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder",<Uri_to_open>,true)
```

As described in the API docs (and whenever I open a folder in vanilla VSCode), the window is refreshed, removing all previously open files.

I now want do stuff within the new window. Like `createTerminal()` or use the `outputChannel`. I've tried both and neither run after the new folder has been opened and the window refreshed. If I use `true` within the `executeCommand()` line, I can see these actions being performed on the "old" window, not in the window of my newly selected folder. How do I ensure when I run window., I'm specifying the new window?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you would have to do this from an extension running _in_ the new window. You could maybe set a flag in the `globalState` that triggers some `if`-branch only if `justOpenedNewWindow` or something.

Comment: Just like flutter, I create a new project ,then it opens a new window and shows log in output.I just want to OpenedNewWindow like this, but when I use ‘await commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder",<Uri_to_open>,true)’,the old one has been closed and it opened a new one.It's not my aim.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I just gave you a suggestion.